# "Отчего" или "от чего" — слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно

В газетной статье встретилось такое предложение:
*Учитывая, что были нерабочие дни, дверь квартиры бронированная, запасных ключей нет, плюс чипы от домофона на той же связке — короче, было, **отчего** понервничать.*

Интересно, как же здесь правильно написать: ***отчего*** или **от чего**?
С одной стороны "отчего" тут в значении "почему", но, с другой стороны, нервничала автор статьи от потери сумки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*отчего* в данном предложении-союзное слово, а именно наречие, пишется слитно(в случае раздельного написания это местоимение с предлогом)

Answer (score 2):

В самом вопросе содержится и ответ. Все-таки здесь возможно двоякое написание, и зависит это именно от смысла, который вкладывает автор. Ср. у Розенталя: Было от чего печалиться (т.е. была причина. объект для данного состояния)

Comment: А вот тут как раз можно говорить полной неразрешимости ситуации. Смысл от выбора варианта написания не меняется.  
"Было отчего печалиться" означает ровно тоже самое, что была причина. Это каксается и обсуждаемого предложения, еслва ли не в большей степени. Не могу сейчас вспомнить точный термин для этой ситуации (что-то наподобие грамматической парасинонимии), но не столь важно. 
Решение ситуации может быть только авторитарным. Принять, например, что правильно раздельное написание и соответвующая этому варианту грамматика.